# C# Maze solver Graphic

Tags: c#, solver, maze

i got a problem with my maze solver when i run the solver it gives a error at the graphic variable

```
 private bool solveMaze(int xPos, int yPos, bool[,] alreadySearched)
        {
            bool correctPath = false;
            bool shouldCheck = true;

            Bitmap map = (Bitmap)Mazebox.Image;
            Graphics gfx = null;
            gfx = Graphics.FromImage(map);
            Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            //out of index check
            if (xPos >= XTILES || xPos < 0 || yPos >= YTILES || yPos < 0)
                shouldCheck = false;

            if (map.GetPixel(xPos , yPos) == Color.Green)
            {
                correctPath = true;
            }
            //Search the Tile
            if (shouldCheck)
            {
                //mark tile as searched
                alreadySearched[xPos, yPos] = true;

                //Check right tile
                correctPath = correctPath || solveMaze(xPos + 1, yPos, alreadySearched);
                //Check down tile
                correctPath = correctPath || solveMaze(xPos, yPos + 1, alreadySearched);
                //check left tile
                correctPath = correctPath || solveMaze(xPos - 1, yPos, alreadySearched);
                //check up tile
                correctPath = correctPath || solveMaze(xPos, yPos - 1, alreadySearched);
            }
            //make correct path gray
            if (correctPath)
            {
                gfx.FillRectangle(b, xPos, yPos, 10, 10);
                Mazebox.Image = map;
            }

            return correctPath;
        }
```

i think the problem is that he opens it alot and then it crash(infinity)
Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Can you include the error?

Comment: I fixed that error but now my problem is it says i cant solve my maze but idk why

Comment: Do you try do implement A* right?

Answer (score 0):

you are never using your `alreadySearched` field.

you can do this by inserting

```
 shouldCheck = shouldCheck && !alreadySearched[xPos, yPos];
```

Comment: hmmmm i did that now but now i can't solve my maze and idk why